# Auto Adapting Image Grid HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, w3c

This is probably way too complicated to be easily implemented, but..
I'm looking either for a already built solution or maybe some tutorials.
Basically, I have a bunch of posters, logos and graphics that I want to display like a portfolio; all images are different dimensions, mostly they are normal poster size, but sometimes there's just a really wide graphic of a text. What I want is to have an automatic image grid, that adapts to the dimensions of images. Ideally I would just provide it a bunch of images and it aligns all of them. I'm building on top of Bootstrap, backend is Django.

[image]

All I can think of right now is writing a script and use Bootstrap rows and columns to decide the size of each column. For example:

```
IN:
A.jpg 100*100px
B.jpg 1100*100px
C.jpg 1200*100px

OUT:
Row 1: [A (width 1)][B (width 11)]
Row 2: [C (width 12)]
```

But that seems unreasonable and complicated. There must be something simpler. If there isn't I will just have to figure out a way to bring all images to the same size.

Comment: I would look into using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: Yes, masonry is the way to go. Have a look at isotope too: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html

Comment: @Andrew thanks for the suggestion. It's a step in the right direction and I'd probably end up using it, but still not exactly right from what I've gathered so far, you still manually specify width and height for elements. Much better than just bootstrap though